# how to store data using jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using this jquery code to store data using ajax but if I use

```
let loc = $('[name="ot_location"]').val(position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude);
```

in console it says `ReferenceError: loc is not defined` I am new to javascript and learning and I need help

html

```
<span>Visit Clear</span><br><input type="checkbox" data-id="{{ $customer->id }}" name="visit_clear" class="js-switch2 js-switch" {{ $customer->visit_clear == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

Java script

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '.js-switch2', function () {
        let visit_clear = $(this).prop('checked') === true ? 1 : 0;
        if ($(this).prop('checked') == 1) {
       $(this).closest('tr').addClass('visitclear');
      //ot get location
       function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else {
        alert("Try any other browser");
      }
    }
    function showPosition(position) {
      let loc = $('[name="ot_location"]').val(position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude);
    }
    $(document).ready(getLocation);
        } else {
           $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('visitclear'); 
        }
        let userId = $(this).data('id');
         
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: '{{ route('users.update.visit_clear') }}',
            data: {'visit_clear': visit_clear, 'user_id': userId , 'ot_location': loc},
            success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Controller

```
public function visitclear(Request $request)
    
    {
        $customer = Customer::findOrFail($request->user_id);
        $customer->visit_clear = $request->visit_clear;
        $customer->ot_location = $request->ot_location;
        $customer->visit_date = date('Y-m-d H:i');
        $customer->save();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'User status updated successfully.']);
    }
```

i want on click check box store geo cords in var loc and store it using ajax how i can do that?

Comment: declare `loc` outside your function so that it will be globally available and see if that works .

Comment: i tried but it does  not store value

Comment: in that line you are just assigning value to your input field .Why don't you simply do `loc =position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude`

Comment: first i was trying to show location on input field and then get it by  var loc = document.getElementById("otlocation").value; and paas it to ajax but not worked

Answer (score 0):

use `var` in place of `let` in your code for  `loc` and see if the reference error goes away.
So, your `let loc = $('[name="ot_location"]').val(position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude);`
should be
`var loc = $('[name="ot_location"]').val(position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude);`